# Is there a reason to not disenchant extra cards?

Tags: hearthstone

Crafting Mode in Hearthstone offers the option to *Mass Disenchant* cards. The in game screen describes the option this way:

> **Disenchant your extra cards to create Arcane Dust**
>   You can't have more than 2 copies of a card in your deck (or more than 1 legendary), so you might as well disenchant the extras and turn them into Arcane Dust!

Is there a reason to hold onto these extra cards? Turning them to dust is permanent and I'm curious as to why the game is giving me the option if the only use for them is to turn them to dust.

Comment: Since this is a CCG basically, there might be a trading feature at some point where you can trade cards you own with other players. If that ever comes, some cards will hold a greater value than others (even cards of the same rarity), and you will generally trade cards of similar total value. Holding on to popular and thus more valuable cards so you can trade them is bound to be much more cost effective than disenchanting. But this doesn't matter if Blizzard never includes such a feature.

Comment: @scenia that would make sense, if you couldn't already create cards you don't have with dust.

Comment: Blizzard will never implement trading.  This is a CCG - and trading would kinda ruin the whole collection process.

Comment: I would like to petition you with an up-vote to accept [Annan's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/165070/53654). Because it's a far wiser answer.

Comment: @JonathanMee Agreed. My answer was very much about the state of the game at that point in time. It probably should have been updated, but I don't play Hearthstone any more.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Come back to the dark side. You didn't eat all the cookies while you were here!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

When a card is changed or nerfed the disenchant reward changes to the same as the enchantment cost for a few weeks. Unless you really need the dust for crafting specific cards it's a better long term investment to wait. Best scenario you get 4X the dust if you wait.

But, if you do need specific cards for your decks it's probably not worth it to speculate on future nerfs. Card changes are not common, so this strategy is most useful if you plan on collecting every card, or every golden card.

Patch notes in the client will list such changes. It is also common for changes to be discussed by streamers or in youtube videos.

The [Card Changes](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Card_changes) page on Gamepedia lists previous changes and ones about to be changed. You can subscribe to notifications for the above page to, most likely, ensure you do not miss a card change. To do so add "Card_Changes" to your [watchlist](http://hearthstone.gamepedia.com/Special:EditWatchlist/raw) after making an account, validating your email and enabling watchlist notifications in your settings. [[more info](http://help.gamepedia.com/Watchlist)]

Comment: Maybe add some information where we can see when a card is in this state

Comment: @Aequitas there's no way to tell if a card is in the state other than the disenchant cost is different. I've added some info about other places that show which cards have been changed.

Answer (score 28):

**NOTE: This answer is historic now as the game has changed. See [Annan's Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/165070/49600).**

Disenchant them! There is no reason to keep any extra cards. Once you have 2 of a card, you can use those two in as many decks as you want.

Additionally, there are two excellent answers to this question about the [science of disenchanting cards in Hearthstone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/138017/559) that you should also read.