# Identifying Uncraftables

Tags: hearthstone

In Hearthstone cards can be disenchanted to provide dust for creating new cards. I generally don't care about golds, so get rid of them to buy things that give me more functional range.

Lately I have been frustrated by the number of 'uncraftable' gold cards I have, which can't be disenchanted and distract from finding the ones I can get rid of.

Is there a way to distinguish uncraftable cards on the 8 card view, or remove them via searches or filters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't filter out uncraftables (I don't know of a way to do that), but it may be helpful for your goal of disposing of golden cards:

If you search for the keyword “**extra**”, then the collection viewer will show every card you have extra copies of (>2 for non-legendary and >1 for legendary), counting regular and golden cards together. This is **not the same as Mass Disenchant,** which counts them separately.

Therefore, all the golden cards you see with this filter are ones that you can disenchant without losing any useful deck-building capabilities. (Don't double click and disenchant 2 goldens if you have only 1 regular!)

(I don't know what the “extra” filter would do with an uncraftable card that you can gain more than 2 copies of, but as far as I know there are no such cards.)

Comment: You have solved the problem rather than the question. Excellent work, thank you.