# Can you do anything with the third copy of a card other than disenchanting it?

Tags: hearthstone

So you can only have 2 copies of each individual card in your deck, so if you get a third copy of a card, you can only disenchant it ... right? Or is there anything - like, really *anything* - you can do with it other than disenchating it? Or can I safely disenchant every third copy of a card I get?

Comment: If you asked this months ago, I would say that one other possibility is to wait for Hearthstone to have the card trading feature, however, the developers already confirmed that they won't be implementing card trading for HS.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136519/is-there-a-reason-to-not-disenchant-extra-cards?rq=1

Comment: The top answer here is better though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is nothing you can do with a third copy. The only reason not to directly disenchant them is if you're speculating on a nerf of that particular card. When Blizzard changes a card you can exchange it for the full dust value for a short time, much more than you usually get.

Comment: when the undertaker got nerfed, did his disenchanting value changed?

Comment: @KarouiHaythem Yes, but only for the Golden versions as the normal version is/was not craftable.

Comment: Glad to know that, didn't mention it