# Are golden cards counted when mass disenchanted? If so, are they or the normal versions disenchanted first?

Tags: hearthstone

When you have 3 or more cards of one type, it is recommended to disenchant extra cards to gain extra dust, and there is no reason to as per [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/136519/is-there-a-reason-to-not-disenchant-extra-cards). When you open many packs at once, it is much easier to go to the "Mass disenchant" section of the collection where it automatically disenchants the duplicate cards.

My question pertaining to this: Are golden cards considered duplicates or do they make regular cards duplicates, causing them to show up as an extra card when Mass Disenchanting? If so, are the golden cards thrown out first or do the regular cards go first?

Comment: It'll disenchant down to 2 of each. Theyre counted seperately

Comment: As supplied [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/386301/identifying-uncraftables), you can use the "extra" keyword to get the crafting interface to find all the times you have more than two of a card across the two formats normal/gold to disenchant things without losing functionality. Not sure if it works with Diamond versions too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Golden and normal cards are separate.  It'll only disenchant them if you have more than 2 golden or 2 normal (1 for legendaries).

If you have 2 normal and 1 golden (or similar) nothing will be disenchanted.